# Bug in PopupMenu when background work is begin done?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am building a Universal App and I think I have found a bug in the Windows Phone 8.1 PopupMenu control. I have been able to reproduce it with a small piece of code. It works fine on Windows 8 but not on Windows Phone 8.1.

Whenever I create a PopupMenu from within a button click it doesn't return from ShowFromSelectionAsync() when there is a background task running ? Why ? 
The same code works on Windows 8.

I my application a lot of background work is being done, so the control doesn't work correctly on Phone anymore. Any suggestions how to fix this ?

I have a MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="PopupMenuBugPhone.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PopupMenuBugPhone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Test Bug" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;


        var task = SimulateBackgroundWork();        // COMMENT THIS TO MAKE IT WORK ON PHONE!!!

        var menu = new PopupMenu();
        var сmdOption1 = new UICommand("Option1");
        var cmdOption2 = new UICommand("Option2");
        menu.Commands.Add(сmdOption1);
        menu.Commands.Add(cmdOption2);

        // We don't want to obscure content, so pass in a rectangle representing the sender of the context menu event.
        var chosenCommand = await menu.ShowForSelectionAsync(frameworkElement.GetElementRect());
        if (chosenCommand == null) // The command is null if no command was invoked.
        {
            await new MessageDialog("No choice").ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await new MessageDialog("Choice: " + chosenCommand.Label).ShowAsync();
        }

        await task;       // COMMENT THIS TO MAKE IT WORK ON PHONE!!!
    }

    private Task SimulateBackgroundWork()
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var dt = DateTime.Now;
            // Do some dummy processing loop
            while (DateTime.Now < dt.AddSeconds(300))
            {
                ;
            }
        });

        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a MenuFlyout?

Let's say you defined it in code-behind of the page, along with the `TaskCompletionSource` to wrap it to make showing awaitable:

```
MenuFlyout flyout = new MenuFlyout();
TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs;
```

Then on button click you could do this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;

    var task = SimulateBackgroundWork(); 

    flyout.Closed += flyout_Closed;

    var mf1 = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Option1" };
    var mf2 = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Option2" };

    mf1.Click += mf_Click;
    mf2.Click += mf_Click;

    flyout.Items.Clear();
    flyout.Items.Add(mf1);
    flyout.Items.Add(mf2);

    await ShowMenuFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);

    await task;
}
```

ShowMenuFlyout is awaitable and implemented like this:

```
public Task<string> ShowMenuFlyout(FrameworkElement sender)
{
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    flyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

And event handlers would simply do this:

```
async void mf_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    flyout.Closed -= flyout_Closed;

    await new MessageDialog("Choice: " + (sender as MenuFlyoutItem).Text).ShowAsync();

    tcs.SetResult((sender as MenuFlyoutItem).Text);
}

async void flyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
{
    flyout.Closed -= flyout_Closed;

    await new MessageDialog("No choice").ShowAsync();

    tcs.SetResult("No choice");
}
```

This works on both platforms. Of course, this is just proof of concept, you might want a null check here or there, but it works.